# using NVDA screen reader with WAI and ARIA...which html tags work?

Tags: html, wai-aria

can someone please inform me as to what html tags work with dynamic content being injected into a page with javascript?

I'm unable to insert plain text nor any other text that is not enclosed with LI and have NVDA read the text out loud?

I've tried using some different html elements like DIV and SPAN and it's not reading it?

Answer (score 0):

we also need to know your browser, could you give us some code ?
normally, when you update a HTML tag with aria-live attribut, it could be announce by screen reader.

Comment: Is this an answer or just a request for clarification?